# How to add a comma to a custom DateTime StringFormat in WPF

Tags: wpf, string-formatting, datetime-format, format-string

I have a date and time being displayed in a textblock. It currently displays "Jun. 21 2013   10:30 AM" with this code

```
<TextBlock
    Style="{StaticResource infoTextBlockStyle}"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="3"
    Text="{Binding SecureMessage.SentTime, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:MMM. dd yyyy   h:mm:ss tt}}" />
```

I want it to display with a comma after the day of the month like this: "Jun. 21, 2013 10:30 AM"

Simply adding a comma after the "dd" generates an error where the trailing format strings cannot be recognized. Is there a way to add a comma to this custom StringFormat?

Comment: I'm no expert, but shouldn't you just escape the comma? (i.e. instead of `dd,` put `dd\,`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap format string in single quotes

```
Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:MMM. dd, yyyy   h:mm:ss tt}'}"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Escaping the comma as Garrett mentioned above also worked.